# Не могу скачать файл через пайтон

Tags: python, requests

Я пытаюсь скачать файл по этой [ссылке](https://r220110.kujo-jotaro.com/naruto/3/1.1080.3b31f76ae73049f4.mp4?hash1=5c470b9d7eb5a67efa247eb8954f0ea1&hash2=584af2322e9ea6c519f24cc3fef7df71), но когда я делаю запрос и скачиваю файл то в .mp4 файле оказқвается этот код;

```html
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.16.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

вот мой код:

```
import requests
f=open(r'1.mp4',"wb")
ufr = requests.post("https://r220110.kujo-jotaro.com/naruto/3/1.1080.3b31f76ae73049f4.mp4?hash1=5c470b9d7eb5a67efa247eb8954f0ea1&hash2=584af2322e9ea6c519f24cc3fef7df71")
f.write(ufr.content)
f.close()
```

Comment: может потому что нужно делать get, а не post? Может нужно указать какие-нибудь заголовки? Аутентификационные данные, например

Comment: @ArchDemon, там еще проще. Там походу авторизация нужна

Comment: А Вы через браузер его скачать можете? (просто у меня не получается к примеру, при попытке получаю вот ровно ту же страницу с `403 Forbidden`, что Вы в ответ добавили)

Comment: @Namerek да я могу скачать через браузер

Answer (score 0):

надо было просто добавить user-agent